# How to set a cookie with PHP and Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony5

My Symfony build project is running at `localhost:8000`. Now I need to create a cookie named `token`.

I am confused about what should be `path` & `domain`? I have tried below code, it is not creating any cookie.

```
$token = JWT::encode($tokenPayload, getenv("JWT_SECRET"));

$useHttps = true;

setcookie("token ", $token , $expireTime, "", "localhost:8000", $useHttps, true);
```

Comment: Why are you using  `useHttps` and `httpOnly`? You seem to be working off the same tutorial than the [person asking this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027486/how-to-implement-multiple-authentication-in-symfony).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a different approach for setting cookies in Symfony. Based on this article: https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/04/03/http-cookies-in-symfony/

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

$cookie = new Cookie(
    'token',
    $token,
    time() + ( 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)  // Expires 2 years.
);
```

Also if you want to use this token to authenticate, I can highly recommend: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle Then you don't have to worry about saving cookies manually.